# Display Price Range on Home Page Left Sider in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.6, magento-1.7

I need to display price range in Home page left side in Magento (ver 1.7.0.2)

**Price Range like.**

All Items Under $10

All Itmes $10 to $20

All Items $20 to $50

All Items $50 to $100

All Items Over $100

Price Range must be created dynamically not static.

**Please give me solution as soon as possible. I really need it.**

Comment: What is the layout you have set for cms home page ?? 1column or 2-column